# Why callback is not called?

Tags: perl, perlapi

I have the example script from [B::OPCheck](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::OPCheck#SYNOPSIS) module with modified `PL_op_name` to [`padsv`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/opcode.h#L158)

```
use B::Generate;

use B::OPCheck padsv => check => sub {
    my $op = shift;
    print "HERE";
};

my $x;
1;
```

But callback is not called.

When deparsing this program I can see this `OP`:

```
$perl -Ilib -Iblib/arch -MO=Terse ~/tmp/xs.pl

LISTOP (0x19828f0) leave [1] 
    OP (0x1c27ef0) enter 
    COP (0x1982938) nextstate 
    OP (0x1982998) padsv [1]           <<<< HERE IT IS
    COP (0x1c27f38) nextstate 
    OP (0x1c27f98) null [5]
```

Why callback is not called?

**UPD**
It seems [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#PL_check) is the answer:

> For most (but not all) types of op, once the op has been initially built and populated with child ops it will be filtered through the check function referenced by the appropriate element of this array

But where to find the list of ops which will be filtered through the check function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find out next thing. I should do

```
wrap_op_checker(OP_PADANY, my_check, &old_checker);
```

Instead of:

```
wrap_op_checker(OP_PADSV, my_check, &old_checker);
```

Because OP of this type **is not created**. At that step it is `OP_PADANY` and **is transformed** into `OP_PADSV` at `Perl_newSVREF` which is called somewhere from [`Perl_yyparse+0x1834`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/perly.y#L1144).

So because of this transformation we can not hook `OP_PADSV`

**UPD**
This behavior do not correspond to the [DOC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Compile-pass-1%3a-check-routines)

> A check routine is called when the node is fully constructed