# Where I can find the types of op that are filtered by PL_check?

Tags: perl, perlapi

[`PL_check`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#PL_check) is a variable exposed by the Perl public API:

> Array, indexed by opcode, of functions that will be called for the "check" phase of optree building during compilation of Perl code. For most (but not all) types of op, once the op has been initially built and populated with child ops it will be filtered through the check function referenced by the appropriate element of this array.

Where in the source code can I see which types of opcode will be filtered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check all types of op. Like the above says, it's an array indexed by opcode.

If you want to know what ops have a checker, that can vary based on what modules you have loaded. For example, [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) adds checkers for 
`OP_PADANY`,
`OP_PADSV`,
`OP_AELEM`,
`OP_HELEM`,
`OP_RV2SV`,
`OP_RV2AV`,
`OP_RV2HV`,
`OP_ASLICE`,
`OP_HSLICE`,
`OP_EXISTS`,
`OP_DELETE`,
`OP_KEYS` and 
`OP_VALUES`. 
(Some of those may already have checkers, in which case autovivifaction's new checker will call the old checker.)

You can find which ops have a built-in checker by looking at the definition of [`PL_check`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/443bd156a6baaf7a8fe6b6b05fcf6c4178140ed2:/opcode.h#l1364) in `opcode.h` (which is generated by `opcode.pl`).

Comment: Thank you. Now I have [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42476409/4632019) to my question.

Comment: I don't see how that helped answer your other question, but awesome! Is it something you learned from autovivification?

Comment: No, I have not look at autovivification and done that by manual tracing. (See [example](https://github.com/KES777/perl/commit/b6e28567043f7deb474285fb40253573a88b589a#diff-0ca05518d51a09e56cb1dcfd96386a4bR9274)) But now I see VERY USEFULL comment there: `Sadly, the padsv OPs we are interested in don't trigger the padsv check function` with the clue above. And based on this I probably resolve another my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434132/how-to-tie-every-variable-in-perl-script)